# Rewarding Players On Kills

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a Minecraft Map where whenever you kill another player your sword upgrades. I have tried doing /scoreboard players add @a[score_Kills=1] Kills 1 and /give @a[score_Kills=1] 283 but it gives the player a kill and an upgraded sword. How do I fix this?

Comment: Read the wiki entries about the [Scoreboard](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard). No need to add 1 to `Kills` every time. 283 is also the Gold Sword and IDs are not recommended to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First did you add the objective? Second if you are in 1.7.10+ you should not be using numbered id's as they are no longer used. make sure that these are activated in order. I recommend chain and repeat command blocks if using 1.9 if not use a [fill clock.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gWg3t7a1wY)
Try this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Kills playerKillCount
```

this is the Kill Count

```
/scoreboard objectives add Level dummy
```

this is the level of sword
levels of sword work like this: wood (level: 1, starting sword), gold, stone, iron, diamond

```
/give @a[score_Kills_min=1,score_level_min=1] minecraft:stone_sword
/scoreboard players add @a[score_Kills_min=1] level 1
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Kills_min=1] Kills 0
```

This process would repeat for every level